# Justification in paracol environment

Tags: paracol, justification, octavo

I would expect full justification in latex unless otherwise specified. This does not work always and it is especially problematic in the paracol environment. Is there a way to automatically force it everywhere?

Sorry I use my actual text instead than lipsum or similar in the MWE. This is to keep the columns balanced. I also put a large part of my preamble, so you can see if there is something problematic.

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
layoutsize={109mm, 190mm},
%layoutoffset={2.5mm, 10mm},
textheight=15.5cm,
textwidth=8.5cm,
inner=1cm,
outer=1.4cm,
top=1.5cm,
bottom=2cm
    ]
    {geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}%%% 

%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.1\textwidth
\columnratio{0.65}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STARTHERE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent
La mia sfida  è di  introdurre il lettore a questa dinamica per mezzo di una scrittura lineare, semplice, ma che cerca di non chiudersi in se stessa. Scrittura che vuole essere innanzitutto una porta, una introduzione, al midrash e al suo paesaggio, attraverso il commento ad alcuni testi, da me scelti, che rappresentano uno  tra gli infiniti percorsi possibili nella foresta della tradizione. Scrittura a margine, che chiosa in vario modo i testi e li trasporta alla lingua corrente, ma anche permette al lettore di sbirciare alle parole in ebraico e in aramaico, e all'oltre delle parole,  aprendo  altre porte, a piè di pagina, che portano ad altri cammini, cedono al piacere della fuga, della variazione, invitano ad altri mondi, altre avventure narrative, sorgenti, tangenti, meridiani, sempre suggeriti, sollecitati, dalla lettura.
\switchcolumn
\noindent
{\scriptsize \textsc{Una nota sulla tipografia} \ Diversi percorsi  possibili si aprono a chi legge, indicati da diverse caratteristiche tipografiche. La parte superiore della pagina presenta il mio commento a testi scelti del midrash, che è anche una  sorta di riflessione su lettura e scrittura nel pensiero dei maestri, un \textit{saggio}, se si vuole, o il percorso dell'ape nel giardino. Il secondo blocco di testo, in corsivo e sulla colonna interna, sono i testi commentati, i fiori se si vuole, la ragion d'essere del nostro leggere, tradotti ed accompagnati, sul lato esterno della pagina, da note puntuali su alcuni termini, che spesso rimandano all'ebraico o all'aramaico dell'originale. A piè di pagina,  si trova la terza par-}\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I run your code and had no issue you are reporting, although I had to comment the line of `New Peninim MT` as I was getting error. Have you looked for any macro changing justification in the main text? You could also add `\definecolumnpreamble{col}{pream}` per column with `\justifying` (the latter requires `ragged2e` package).

Comment: Your use of `\scriptsize` is wrong if you use `{ }` you should end the paragraph before `}`

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment on \scriptsize. Can you write an example of how I should use it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns are justified but Tex warns:

```
Overfull \hbox (8.41423pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 46--47
[]\TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n/8 ratteristiche tipografiche. La[]

Overfull \hbox (5.04361pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 46--47
[]\TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n/8 na presenta il mio commen-[]

Overfull \hbox (1.50227pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 46--47
[]\TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n/8 to a testi scelti del midrash,[]
```

add `\sloppy` after `\begin{document}` to allow more flexibility:

[image]

The use of `\scriptsize` is wrong, it is using small text on a large baseline as the paragraph is not ended in the scope. Adding a blank line gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
layoutsize={109mm, 190mm},
%layoutoffset={2.5mm, 10mm},
textheight=15.5cm,
textwidth=8.5cm,
inner=1cm,
outer=1.4cm,
top=1.5cm,
bottom=2cm
    ]
    {geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}%%% 

%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.1\textwidth
\columnratio{0.65}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
%\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STARTHERE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\sloppy

\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent
La mia sfida  è di  introdurre il lettore a questa dinamica per mezzo di una scrittura lineare, semplice, ma che cerca di non chiudersi in se stessa. Scrittura che vuole essere innanzitutto una porta, una introduzione, al midrash e al suo paesaggio, attraverso il commento ad alcuni testi, da me scelti, che rappresentano uno  tra gli infiniti percorsi possibili nella foresta della tradizione. Scrittura a margine, che chiosa in vario modo i testi e li trasporta alla lingua corrente, ma anche permette al lettore di sbirciare alle parole in ebraico e in aramaico, e all'oltre delle parole,  aprendo  altre porte, a piè di pagina, che portano ad altri cammini, cedono al piacere della fuga, della variazione, invitano ad altri mondi, altre avventure narrative, sorgenti, tangenti, meridiani, sempre suggeriti, sollecitati, dalla lettura.
\switchcolumn
\noindent
{\scriptsize \textsc{Una nota sulla tipografia} \ Diversi percorsi  possibili si aprono a chi legge, indicati da diverse caratteristiche tipografiche. La parte superiore della pagina presenta il mio commento a testi scelti del midrash, che è anche una  sorta di riflessione su lettura e scrittura nel pensiero dei maestri, un \textit{saggio}, se si vuole, o il percorso dell'ape nel giardino. Il secondo blocco di testo, in corsivo e sulla colonna interna, sono i testi commentati, i fiori se si vuole, la ragion d'essere del nostro leggere, tradotti ed accompagnati, sul lato esterno della pagina, da note puntuali su alcuni termini, che spesso rimandano all'ebraico o all'aramaico dell'originale. A piè di pagina,  si trova la terza par-

}\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The \sloppy command seems to work well. Will try in other parts of my book and will update.

Comment: For \scriptsize, if I go with your suggestion the space in between line is too small. In fact I do want script size and normal space in between lines... Is there another better way I can obtain this? Thanks

Comment: select \scriptsze then set \baselineskip=\normalbaselineskip  otherwise if you have 2 or more paragraphs in the second column, all but the last will use the smaller baseline @Haim

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I do not know where to place the \baselineskip command... Can you place it in your answer? Thanks

Comment: @Haim actually probably needs `{\scriptsize\setlength\baselineskip{14.4pt}\textsc{Una nota sulla tipografia} .....`

Comment: This works perfectly thanks!